# Lyapunov Spectrum of the Lorenz System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, jacobian, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the Lorenz System

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\frac {\mathrm {d} x}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=\sigma (y-x),\\[6pt]{\frac {\mathrm {d} y}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=x(\rho -z)-y,\\[6pt]{\frac {\mathrm {d} z}{\mathrm {d} t}}&=xy-\beta z.\end{aligned}}} {\displaystyle }$$

and its jacobi matrix

$$\boldsymbol{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
-\sigma & \sigma & 0\\
\rho & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -b
\end{bmatrix}$$

In [Paper, Eq. 6](https://journals.aps.org/pra/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevA.29.2928) they claim:

> Since the trace of the Jacobian is constant it follows that:

$$Tr(\boldsymbol{J})= - \sigma -1 - b = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\lambda_i$$

So the sum of the lyapunov exponents is equal to the trace of the jacobian.

Does someone know how this relation can be derived?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}$
This is true for any matrix, as
$$
\tr(A)=\tr(Q^{-1}AQ)
$$
and if you take the transformation to Jordan normal form, you get the claimed identity. Also
$$
\tr(A^k)=\tr((Q^{-1}AQ)^k)=\sum_{j=1}^n(λ_j)^k.
$$

---

For your specific problem, you have a differential equation $\dot u=f(u)$ and the partial derivatives $U(t)=\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial x_0}$ wrt. the initial point. These satisfy the differential equation $\dot U(t)=J(x(t))U(t)$. Now 
$$
t\sum_{j=1}^n λ_j = \ln(|\det(U(t))|)
$$ 
by definition of the process. We know that the derivative of the determinant is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\det(U(t))
=\det(U(t))\tr(U(t)^{-1}\dot U(t))
=\det(U(t))\tr(\dot U(t)U(t)^{-1})
\\
=\det(U(t))\tr(J(x(t))
$$
Now if $\tr(J(x(t))$ is a constant, then 
$$
\det(U(t))=\det(U(0))e^{t\tr(J(x_0))}
\implies
\tr(J(x_0))=\sum_{j=1}^n λ_j,
$$
using $U(0)=I\implies \ln|\det(U(0))|=0$, which proves the claim.

Comment: Where do u use the assumption: Since the trace of the Jacobian is constant. For a dynamical system that does not have this property the above mentioned relation between the sum of the lyapunov exponents and trace of the jacobian is no longer true.

Comment: Nowhere. As I said, this is a general property for square matrices, independent of if they are Jacobians or not.